# http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org api giving httpcode 403

Tags: openstreetmap, http-status-code-403, nominatim

api call to http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json started giving httpcode 403.

We are using this api since last 2 years and never faced such issue.

Suddenly today it started giving this error.

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Comment: Works for me. Http-Code 200 - Response: `[ ]`.  What exactly looks you real call like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added HTTP Referrer and it worked!
As per their usage policy , valid HTTP Referrer is required.
However not sure about how it used to work earlier.

Comment: Please also check the other requirements from the [usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/).

Comment: From what I can understand from elsewhere, people have been abusing the volunteer-provided resources at nominatim.openstreetmap.org, and this required a "crackdown" where people hadn't been following the usage policy.  That might be why you've seen a change in recent days.  If this causes a problem, perhaps it would be a good idea to check out a commercial provider instead?